# Rails: How do I map out this has_many, has_many association?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model-associations

I'm currently working on a game for a student project. I'm spinning in circles engineering the associations. Any guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated.

There are 3 models/classes: **Games, Characters and Quotes.**

**Game:**

- has_many Characters (two historical characters with a bank of quotes, you will have to choose who said the quote)
- has_many Quotes (through games)

**Character:**

- has_many Games (to keep track of games a character has appeared in)
- has_many Quotes

**Quote:**

- belongs_to Character

```ruby
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :characters
  # Each game will have exactly 2 characters 
  # @game.characters will return the two characters
  has_many :quotes, through: :characters   
end

class Characters < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :games
  # @character.games will return all games the character appeared in
  has_many :quotes 
end

class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :character
end
```

These are the migrations I've created:

```ruby
class CreateGames < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :games do |t|
      t.text :game_state
    end
  end
end

class CreateCharacters < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :characters do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :title
    end
  end
end

class CreateQuotes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :quotes do |t|
      t.string :content
      t.belongs_to :character, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Goals:

1. instantiate a new game with two characters: `@game =
   Game.new(@character1, @character2)`
2. `@game.characters` should return
   the two characters.
3. `@character1.games` should return all games
   the character appeared in.
4. `@game.quotes` should return all the
   quotes from the two characters.

My first instinct is that I need a join table for the has_many has_many relationship and to keep track of the games. For example:.

```ruby
class GamesPlayed < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :character1
  belongs_to :character2
  belongs_to :game
end
```

Thanks in advance if you can offer me any guidance or suggestions.

Comment: To make sure I follow you: Game and Character has a many to many association between them? I think you need a join table for that.

Comment: Yes, Game and Character have_many of each, I did map out a prototype of a join table but the syntax is looking fishy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written your associations, you haven't really fleshed out the many to many association between the Game & Character models. Basically you'll need a join table for that.

In it's simplest form, it will look something like:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_character_joins
  has_many :characters, through: :game_character_joins
end

class Characters < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :game_character_joins
  has_many :games, through: :game_character_joins

end

class GameCharacterJoin < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
  belongs_to :character
end
```

The migrations for the join table would be:

```
class CreateGameCharacterJoin < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :game_character_joins do |t|
      t.integer :game_id
      t.integer :character_id
    end
  end
end
```

That's really the easier part of what I think you're asking.

Then, the association between Quote and Game is kind of odd looking to me. Is this because you need to get all the Quotes for a single Game? There are a lot of ways to model that--is the idea of an association between Quote and Game a matter of convenience? It seems to me that a quote is

1. requires both a character and a game,
2. owned by a character
3. is about a game

How you approach this really becomes a matter of preference. Depending on the importance of the associations, you can have a many to many between character & quote and another between game & quote, or you can just rely on additional data in the quote table to specify which game it's about.

Comment: I forgot the migrations...one moment

Comment: Note: there's no need for a model to represent the join if there's no additional logic or data stored there. ActiveRecord supports `has_and_belongs_to_many` using just a join *table* with no corresponding model.

Comment: @jaydel, thank you so much for your response.

For the join table migration, I am confused because how do I associate two characters? Currently you only have one character_id in the table and I need two for each game.

Comment: each row of the join table will represent an association between one game and one player. I was assuming for each game, there would be two rows in this table, each pointing at a different character. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, ok, that does make sense. That's extremely helpful, I wasn't thinking about it that way. In my head everything needed to happen on the same row

Answer (score 1):

To model a many-to-many relationship you can use either a `has_and_belongs_to_many` which would rely on a join table (no model), or a model that represents the relationship between the two models.

I wonder if you  don't really have a many-to-many relationship though. Consider this instead:

```
class Game
  belongs_to :player_one, class_name: 'Player'
  belongs_to :player_two, class_name: 'Player'
  scope :for_player, ->(player) { where(player_one: player).or(where(player_two: player)) }

  def players
    Player.where(id: [player_one_id, player_two_id])
  end
end

class Player
  def games
    Game.for_player(self)
  end
end

# In use:
@game = Game.find(1)
@game.players
@player = Player.find(1)
@player.games
@player.games.where(created_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today)
```

Note that both `game.players` and `player.games` return an `ActiveRecord_Relation` that you can use in additional scopes, you just don't have a `has_many` on the `Player` model.

Comment: IMO this is the cleanest and simplest solution. I don't understand why you got a downvote.

Comment: Well, this approach is not generic.
What if the requirement changes and now each game can have three characters instead of two?

What I believe is that a solution must be generic.

Comment: @NimishGupta There are plenty of schools of thought on writing good code. You prefer genericization and predicting the future. I prefer writing code that is expressive and amenable to change. Agree to disagree.

Comment: @coreyward: thanks for your response!

I should have been more clear, a game doesn't have any human players. It has historical characters, like Hitler, Stalin, Mussolini and a each of those characters of a bunch of quotes. So each game would be composed of two historical characters and the user will have to figure out who said what.

Comment: Agile: you only know what you know--don't code for an unforeseeable future. I like that you've taken the OPs assertion that there will be exactly 2 players per game. I wrestled with it in my answer but eventually decided to address his confusion about the many to many join.

Comment: @coreyward Well, thoughts may differ :)
Have a nice day mate.

Comment: @JoelB Should be able to sub-in `Character` for `Player`, I just wanted to give a more classic example so this answer is useful for others who come across it. Holler if you need any help making that change.

Comment: @coreyward: Thanks for being so helpful. Most of the code makes sense for me aside from this line: `scope :for_player, ->(player) { where(player_one: player).or(where(player_two: player)) }`

Comment: @JoelB Which part doesn't make sense? Maybe one of these things will help: The `scope` is like a class method. That `where` method call is on `self`, which is an instance of `Game`, so like `game.where`. The little `->` incantation is called the “stabby lambda” and it's just converting the block (in the curly braces) into a Proc so ActiveRecord can call it later. The actual `where(...).or(where(...))` results in simple SQL like `WHERE player_one_id = 1 OR player_two_id = 1`.